# Android ORMLite get error with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite in my project and everything is Ok until use Proguard, when I use proguard I'm getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not find public constructor with ConnectionSource and optional Class parameters class my.package.myDaoImpl.  Missing static on class?

My proguard config file:

```
# ORMLite
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

SOLVED, I used this to keep my DAO classes members, enum and interface.

```
-keep class mypackage.example.**
-keepclassmembers class mypackage.example.** {*;}
-keep enum mypackage.example.**
-keepclassmembers enum mypackage.example.** { *; }
-keep interface mypackage.example.**
-keepclassmembers interface mypackage.example.** { *; }
```

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ormlite+proguard

Comment: I use some configurations on my proguard config file, but don't work. I will edit the question with proguard config.